# Cluster map in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have to make a cluster map view in Drupal 7 with location coming from existing field (Country name).

I have tried leaflet cluster map & geocluster.

Please Help me out , I am a newbie in Drupal & thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner in Drupal you first have to learn from tutorials like "Drupal for site Builders".

Once you learn about views and content types, which is what you need at least, this video could be helpful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_VIIq-EuEo

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for replay. But I have already gone through this video and I didn't find anything.

Comment: I am using leaflet + geofield + leaflet markercluster to make cluster map but map is showing blank.